PyInstaller - Pandas
Seeing this error while trying to run an exe generated by PyInstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_program.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "pandas\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.


How are you importing packages in my_program.py?
